# Angular universal `renderModule` `extraProviders` ignored

Tags: angular, dependency-injection, server-side-rendering, angular-universal

I am rendering my Angular app on the server using `renderModule` and trying to pass `extraProviders` with some information generated by the backend, but they are getting ignored, here's the Typescript code for the server side rendering:

```js
renderModule(AppServerModule, {
  url,
  document,
  extraProviders: [
    { provide: APP_IS_MOBILE, useValue: true }
  ]
}).then(x => console.log(x));
```

And here's where I try to use it:

`app.server.module.ts`

```js
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    AppModule,
    ServerModule,
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppServerModule {
  constructor(@Inject(APP_IS_MOBILE) isMobile: boolean) {
    console.error('AppServerModule isMobile', isMobile);
  }
}
```

The log I'm getting is only ever `AppServerModule isMobile false` even though the extra providers provide a `true` value.

What am I doing wrong? How can I make this work?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As happens more often than not, simply asking the question points me to the answer... I had accidentally overridden this provider in the app.module.ts of the browser app, with a `false` provided value.

Nothing to see here, move along...